# Using Win32::OLE to execute macro in Access 2007

Tags: perl, winapi, ms-access, ole

Currently I am trying to execute a macro in Microsoft Access through Perl OLE

I am wondering how to properly make the call to run a macro. I have tried

1) `$oDatabase -> DoCmd.RunMacro("Macro1");`
2) `$oDatabase -> DoCmd -> RunMacro("Macro1");`

But they throw me "Can't call method "DoCmd" on an undefined value" or "useless use of concatentation"

Is this even possible to execute a DoCmd through Win::32 OLE? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a complete code. It tries to look for the current Microsoft Access that is opened.

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 
use Win32::OLE;

my $oAccess;
my $oDatabase;

my $filename = "C:\\Sample.accdb"; 
$oAccess = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Access.Application');

$oDatabase = $oAccess->OpenCurrentDatabase($filename);
$oDatabase -> DoCmd.RunMacro("Macro1");
```

Comment: I think others have actually answered your question, but I would ask what the hell you're want to run a *macro* for. Macros are a terrible way to get anything done in an Access application. What does the macro do? It's very likely that it can done much more directly through some other method, i.e., real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Microsoft's rather confusing documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb149125.aspx), [DoCmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb237480.aspx) is a **property** of the Application object, and [RunMacro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214052.aspx) is a **method** of DoCmd.  In Win32::OLE, methods use method syntax and properties use hash syntax.  (The dot '.' is Visual Basic syntax.  In Perl 5, use a '->').

So the last two lines of your code should be (I think):

```
$oAccess->OpenCurrentDatabase($filename);
$oAccess->{DoCmd}->RunMacro("Macro1");
```

I don't have Access 2007 so I can't test this.

Note that [OpenCurrentDatabase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238012.aspx) does not return anything, which is why you're getting "Can't call method "DoCmd" on an undefined value" when you try to call methods on $oDatabase (which is undef).

*Links to Microsoft's documentation worked on August 23, 2009, but Microsoft has never read [Cool URIs don't change](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI), so your mileage may vary.*

Answer (score -1):

As HansUp said, you should use Access's Application instance variable to use DoCmd.
In your case, it will translate to

```
$oAccess->DoCmd.RunMacro("macro1");
```

Note: I don't know Perl :)

Comment: When down-voting, please explain the reason. Thanks :)

Comment: I wasn't the voter, but my guess would be it was down-voted because that's not the correct syntax for doing that in Perl.

Comment: Thanks cjm. I took it from the OP's question and I said that I don't know PERL :)

Comment: Unfortunately, half his problem is that he's gotten the syntax wrong. :-)