# Exporting Access Tables Programmatically

Tags: java, php, ms-access, ado, autoit

alright, after a few hours of searching and reading all over the net, I have broken down and decided to ask for help. I am working to automate many of the more medial and repetitive tasks as work, and stumbled upon AutoIt, I love the tool. anyway, Today's task is the export of a slew of tables and queries from Access 2007 in a few different formats. mostly CSVs some Tab delimited, and a couple of dBase DBFs and DBTs. now none of this is all that difficult and in fact the person who previously held my position created about a hundred Macros in the mdb that export the tables. seems to me that he fell well short of hastening the process as you still have to run each macro. I am looking to create an autoit script that will export the correct tables in the correct format to the correct place with the correct name. doesn't seem like it should be that difficult.

so thus far I have been imagining using ADO to tell Access to export which table in which format and where. but I cannot seem to find the necessary commands needed to do that. I also figured that perhaps, at least with the text based formats (CSV, txt, tab) I could read each record out of a given table or query and then build the text file myself in autoit, not the simplest way of doing it, but it could work. The problem arises when trying to create the dBase file, I haven't a clue where to begin with that.

I am open to using JAVA, AutoIt, PHP, or Perl to accomplish my task.

I should note that I am fairly new to ADO. the syntax in ADO seems to elude me frequently. so, any and all help is appreciated, please refrain from the "Just google it" responses. if you have a link to share, or a resource that you have found helpful please post that as well, I am not allergic to reading or doing research. Sometimes it just makes more sense to ask for help.

Thanks,

Kyle

Comment: is there a way to use the DoCmd object in another Language? I would like to avoid having to deal with the learning curve of a new language, at least for the near term.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using VBA, you could probably make it work with only a little code and the DoCmd-Object.

To export as CSV, have a look at [DoCmd.Transfertext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220768%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

To export to dBase, have a look at [DoCmd.TransferDatabase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214131%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

If you have questions about using those, just ask in the comments and I will provide more information.

Comment: I am not familiar with VBA as I have never used it. I am not sure I even now where to begin writing a VBA application, much less how to run it.

I would like to accomplish this task without having to learn yet another syntax and naming convention. I am sure VBA is a great tool, I just already have more than enough languages in my repertoire. that said, if I can't make it work in what I know, it is time to learn something that I can get it done with. 

I am curious what exactly the DoCmd object does, and if I can replicate it in one of the langs I already know.

Comment: DoCmd lets you access functionality you would use the GUI for (or a macro) in VBA. Your export to csv function would only need one line of code for example. (`DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , _
    "NameOfYourTable", "C:\Path\To\Your\CSV.txt"`)  Stuff like export to dBase etc. is already built into Access, so you can use it with DoCmd

Comment: so, I could build a macro into the access mdb that has a line of code for each export i need to do, then call that macro from an autoit script?

Comment: I have never used AutoIt or a macro (you can do everything a macro can in VBA), so I can't say anything about that. But your requirements should be fairly easy to fullfil with VBA (even with only a little knowledge of the language)

Comment: Ok, I have a solution for your language problem I guess. You can use win32-ole objects to access DoCmd. Here is a example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314637/using-win32ole-to-execute-macro-in-access-2007

Comment: @cularis: But that solution is just using the same VBA commands via automation. That's like wearing thick gloves while performing surgery, since you STILL have to know the commands and syntax. Better to just code it up natively in VBA and be done with it, seems to me.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton yes I know, but he wanted to use a language he is more familiar with ;)

Comment: There is no simpler way to do this than using the built-in VBA function. Sure, you can use a different language and have to write code that's 100x more lines, but really, does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

This is a sort of bonkers idea, but if you already know Java, you may be able to get this to work with the [JDBC-ODBC bridge](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/bridge.doc.html). You'll first have to register your particular Access database as a named ODBC data source, as the bridge does not appear to support on-the-fly ODBC. I don't have a Windows machine on hand and don't remember the exact sequence of steps to do that, but it should be available from the ODBC driver manager.